# How to get mustache templates to work in brunch

Tags: coffeescript, mustache, brunch

I want to use mustache templates with Brunch. This is my config.coffee file:

```
{languages, plugins} = require 'brunch-extensions'

# Make config loadable via require() for brunch.
exports.config =
  # Available plugins:
  # * AssetsPlugin: copy `app/assets` contents to `build/`
  plugins: [plugins.AssetsPlugin]

  # Contains a list of output filenames that your application would generate.
  # Format:
  #
  # 'filename': 
  #   languages:
  #     'regExp, with which input files will be matched': language class
  #   order:
  #     before: [files, that would be loaded before anything else]
  #     after: [files, that would be loaded after anything else]
  #
  files:
    'scripts/app.js':
      languages:
        '\.js$': languages.JavaScriptLanguage
        '\.coffee$': languages.CoffeeScriptLanguage
        '\.eco$': languages.EcoLanguage
        '\.mustache$': languages.HoganLanguage
      order:
        before: [
          'vendor/scripts/console-helper.js'
          'vendor/scripts/jquery-1.7.js'
          'vendor/scripts/underscore-1.1.7.js'
          'vendor/scripts/backbone-0.5.3.js'
        ]

    'styles/app.css':
      languages:
        '\.css$': languages.CSSLanguage
        '\.styl$': languages.StylusLanguage
      order:
        before: ['vendor/styles/normalize.css']
        after: ['vendor/styles/helpers.css']
```

But I got the following error when start `brunch watch`:

```
[17:27:45]: [Brunch]: cannot parse config entry 
config.files['scripts/app.js'].languages['.mustache$']: TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out

Comment: Nope. It seems they drop the mustache support, as I couldn't find any reference in the languages folder.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it seems that there is no mustache support in brunch-extensions 0.2.2. What you can do is either install brunch-extensions directly from the master branch:

```
npm install https://github.com/brunch/brunch-extensions/tarball/master
```

Or you can add your own `HoganLanguage`, from [their github](https://github.com/brunch/brunch-extensions/blob/master/src/languages/hogan.coffee):

```
hogan = require 'hogan.js'
{BaseLanguage} = require './base'

# Requires Hogan 1.0.4
#
# Example:
# $(@el).html(template.render name: "mdp", city: "SF")
class exports.HoganLanguage extends BaseLanguage
  compile: (path, callback) ->
    @readFile path, (error, data) =>
      return callback error if error?
      try
        content = hogan.compile data, asString: yes
        callback null, "exports.render = function(data) {
          var t = new Hogan.Template();
          t.r = #{content};
          return t.render(data);
        }"
      catch error
        callback error
```

It should work fine if you just install `hogan.js` and change to `{BaseLanguage} = require 'brunch-extensions/lib/languages/base'` above.

Comment: I was told I need to upgrade brunch-extensions to 0.3 and it should work. Will do that tonight.